# C++ Doubly Linked List with Pointers: Object of class isn't constructed properly

Tags: c++, data-structures, circular-list

I am in the process of implementing a circular linked list in C++.

I want to use my static function for printing during testing; however, `stdout` isn't executed (nothing prints to the console). I have been trying to figure out the cause of the crash, but I am stuck.

Note that I have wandered outside of the spec of circular linked lists, and implemented a variable named `tail`, which stores the address to the variable to the left of the head. It seemed like a way to simplify the problem at the time.

**Main function:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Testing linked_list class:" << endl;
    linked_list::linked_list_test();
}
```

**linked_list.h:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class linked_list {
private:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;

        Node() {
            value = 0;
            next = nullptr;
            previous = nullptr;
        }

        Node(int n) {
            value = n;
            next = nullptr;
            previous = nullptr;
        }

        Node(int n, Node* p) {
            value = n;
            next = p;
        }
    };

    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    Node* get_node(int index) {
        if(index < 0 or index >= size) {
            throw out_of_range("IndexError: Index out of range");
        }

        Node* current = head;
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        return current;
    }

public:
    linked_list();
    linked_list(vector<int> initial);
    ~linked_list();

    int operator [](int i);

    int length();

    int pop(int index);
    int pop();

    void insert(int value, int index);
    void remove(int index);
    void append(int value);
    void print();

    static void linked_list_test();
};

#endif
```

**linked_list.cpp:**

```
#include "linked_list.h"


linked_list::linked_list() {
    size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

linked_list::~linked_list() {
    Node* current;
    Node* next;

    current = head;

    while (current != nullptr) {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}

int linked_list::operator[] (int index) {
    return get_node(index) -> value;
}

linked_list::linked_list(vector<int> initial) {
    size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;

    for (int n: initial) {
        append(n);
    }
}

int linked_list::length() {
    return size;
}

void linked_list::append(int value) {
    if(head == nullptr && tail == nullptr) {
        head = new Node(value);
        tail = head;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    tail -> next = new Node(value);
    tail = tail ->next;
    size++;
}

void linked_list::remove(int index) {
    if(index == 0) {
        Node* current = head -> next;
        delete head;
        head = current;

    }
    else if(index == size -1) {
        Node* current = tail -> next;
        delete tail;
        tail = current;
    }

    Node* current;
    Node* previous = new Node;
    current = head;
    for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    previous->next = current->next;

    size--;
}

int linked_list::pop(int index) {
    if(index <= size) {
        int n = get_node(index) -> value;
        remove(index);

        return n;
    }

    else if(index > size) {
        throw out_of_range("IndexError");
    }
}

int linked_list::pop() {
    return pop(size - 1);
}

void linked_list::insert(int val, int index) {
    Node* previous = get_node(index-1);
    Node* next = previous -> next;
    previous ->next = new Node(val, next);
}

void linked_list::print() {
    Node* current = head;
    cout << "[";
    while (current->next != nullptr) {
        cout << current->value;
        cout << ", ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << current->value << "]" << endl;
}

void linked_list::linked_list_test() {
    linked_list dynamic_list;
    dynamic_list.print();
    dynamic_list.append(9);
    dynamic_list.append(2);

    cout <<"appended 9 and 2"<< endl;
    dynamic_list.print();

    cout << "Instantiating an array with elements 3, 4, and 5" << endl;
    linked_list t_array({3, 4, 5});
    t_array.print();

    cout << "Inserting 6 to index 1 on the new array" << endl;
    t_array.insert(1, 6);
    t_array.print();

    cout << "Using pop() to remove last element in list" << endl;
    t_array.print();
}
```

Comment: "Like many other people here on stackoverflow, I am also in the process of implementing a doubly linked list" - unfortunately probably true. But have you actually tried to _use_ one (for example `std::list`) to actually write a useful application?

Comment: hey, your linked_list.h is actually your linked_list.cpp

Comment: I am not sure I understand @NeilButterworth

Comment: @phillipvoyle that would be incorrect sir

Comment: No he's correct. Look at your question. You have pasted in  the same code for linked_list.h and linked_list.cpp.

Comment: The fact that I am doing what many people are doing doesn't make a difference I am having difficulty constructing the class making it not strictly speaking a linked list problem but rather something more in general

Comment: I believe he's referring to what you have actually pasted into the question, you .h file contains .c code

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say nothing is printed to the console ? appended 9 and 2"  ?

Comment: I am running this method linked_list::linked_list_test(), and I should be getting a mutiple lines of strings as output. I get nothing

Comment: Side note: Placing `using namespace std;` at file scope in a header can have disastrous consequences. Do this only after long consideration and with extremely good reasons.

Comment: I appologize @phillipvoyle, I just saw that I didn't include the .h file. It is up now.

Comment: `linked_list::pop` promises to return int, but does not do this on all paths. On second glance, this will just be anal compiler barking. if `index <= size` is not true, `index > size` is implied.

Comment: @user4581301 good point. This class won't be longer than 250 lines of code, and is quite easy to maintain. The main reason I am doing it is because of directives from the course supervisor. I expect to use your method, the current consensus on good programming, if I ever was to develop code in C++

Comment: @CanHicabiTartanoglu *(meaning I am almost done)!* -- Umm, not quite:  `{linked_list a; a.append(10); linked_list b = a;}`.  Double-`delete[]` error.  Your class lacks a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Important note: For a doubly linked list, this gets no use out of the `Node::previous` pointer. This is likely to cost marks as this is pretty much the point of a doubly linked list.

Comment: @user4581301 you got A<->B<->C, assuming we don't have previous how does it point both directions?

Comment: My point is `previous` is not being used. It's always `nullptr`. In it's place you are using `get_node` with `index-1`, a slow and painful why to find the previous node when you should already have a pointer to it in hand. This is what @phillipvoyle is in the process of fixing in his edits.

Answer (score 3):

I think what I'd start with is your print function, which doesn't deal well with the case where the list is empty. Here I've made sure not to use the pointer `current` when it's null. We can be sure that it's safe to use it within the while loop scope because I've constrained it to `current != nullptr`

```
void linked_list::print() {
    Node* current = head;
    cout << "[";
    bool bFirst = true;
    while (current != nullptr) {  // was current->next
        if (bFirst) {
            bFirst = false;
        } else {
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << current->value;
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << "]" << endl; //no longer referencing current->value here where it's unsafe
}
```

you also need to take care of the book keeping on both the next and previous pointers when inserting or removing nodes

```
void linked_list::append(int value) {
    if(head == nullptr && tail == nullptr) {
        head = new Node(value);
        tail = head;
    } else { 
        tail->next = new Node(value);
        tail->next->previous = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    size++;
}
```

And

```
void linked_list::remove(int index) {
    Node* current = head;
    for (int i = 0; (i < index) && (current != null) ; i++) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current != null) {
        Node* next = current->next;
        Node* previous = current->previous;

        if (next == null) {
            tail = previous; // no next
        } else {
            next->previous = previous;
        }

        if (previous == null) {
            head = next; //no previous
        } else {
            previous->next = next;
        }
        size --; //only if we found something
    }
}
```

Comment: I will add your contribution to the question (giving you credit)

Comment: @CanHicabiTartanoglu As the answer to Why doesn't print work, this pretty much is the answer. You should select it as the answer and start writing up the next question which deals with the bug in `insert`.

Comment: Would the append work for circular linked lists also?

Comment: And is @user4581301 correct saying that previous is redundant? You made the append method keeping previous

Comment: @CanHicabiTartanoglu I guess for a circular linked list you might not need a tail? Just a head. I've never tried to implement one of those. If it were doubly linked you would still have to pay attention to your head and your previous pointers and make sure they don't get stale when making changes.

Comment: @CanHicabiTartanoglu You mis-interpret. I'm not saying it is redundant, I'm saying that it was left unused in your implementation. As `previous` is the secret sauce that makes a doubly linked list work, this is an odd design choice. Philip is showing you how to fix this problem.

Comment: Regarding circular linked list, one step at a time. Get the regular linked list working first, then worry about looping it around. You may find drawing pictures helps you visualize the list. If you draw the list very carefully and take good notes on what you did and how you did it the notes can form the basis for the code. They also form a great set of expectations to compare against when debugging.

Comment: In circular: void CircLinkedList::append(int value) {
    if(head == nullptr && tail == nullptr) {
        head = new Node(value);
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail->next = new Node(value);
        tail->next->previous = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    size++;
}